# detect when user changes hash in the url and hits enter (i mean submit after change in hash in url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

to bind a function to the hash change event. This seems to work in IE8, Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari and I assume not in earlier version of IE. For these browsers, I want to disable my JavaScript code that uses the hash and hashchange event.

Is there a way with jQuery that i can detect if the browser detect the hashchange event  with when user press enter after changing the hash? Maybe something with jQuery.support...

Comment: Hi have a look at this article [http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)